# WordPress User ID as Shortcode

Tags: shortcode

I want to use this as a shortcode to show in any post/page

```
<?php 
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    if ($user_id == 0) {
        echo 'You are currently not logged in.';
    } else {
        echo 'You are logged in as user '.$user_id;
    }
?>
```

when I do this

```
// Add Shortcode
function uniqueID_shortcode() {

    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    if ($user_id == 0) {
        echo 'You are currently not logged in.';
    } else {
        echo 'You are logged in as user '.$user_id;
    }

}
add_shortcode( 'naveen', 'uniqueID_shortcode' );
```

Gutenberg through an error of Updating failed, how to solve this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`add_shortcode`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode)

> ...Note that the function called by the shortcode should never produce output of any kind. Shortcode functions should return the text that is to be used to replace the shortcode. Producing the output directly will lead to unexpected results...

Try changing the `echo`s in your callback to `return`s and see, if that helps.

Comment: Thank You, it is working 